# Yii2 Generating translation messages

Tags: php, internationalization, yii2

In Yii 1.x we generated translation messages with command
  `./framework/yiic message protected/messages/config.php`
How can we achieve the same with Yii2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just run using yiic file in root directory of your project (where composer.json is).
Here is help from the yiic.
If you have specific problem let me know.

> ./yii help message
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> Extracts messages to be translated from source files.
>
> The extracted messages can be saved the following depending on format
>   setting in config file:
>
> - PHP message source files.
> - ".po" files.
> - Database.
>
> Usage:
>   1. Create a configuration file using the 'message/config' command:    yii message/config /path/to/myapp/messages/config.php
>   2. Edit the created config file, adjusting it for your web application needs.
>   3. Run the 'message/extract' command, using created config:    yii message /path/to/myapp/messages/config.php
>
> SUB-COMMANDS
>
> - message/config: Creates a configuration file for the "extract" command.
> - message/extract (default): Extracts messages to be translated from source c...
>
> To see the detailed information about individual sub-commands, enter:
>
> yii help